# C# API for Bugzilla 2.2

Tags: c#, bugzilla

I understand the Bugzilla C# Proxy exists for accessing Bugzilla 3.0 via C#, but is there an option for Bugzilla 2.2?  What about accessing the underlying MySQL db - is the schema documented?  I only really need basic search (bug #) and limited update (target, status comment) capabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the Bugzilla schema for most versions at [Ravenbrook](http://www.ravenbrook.com/project/p4dti/tool/cgi/bugzilla-schema/).

It looks like the Bugzilla C# Proxy is for version 3.0+, so you're out of luck there. I'm pretty confident the Web Services were not available in 2.2.  Is there some reason you're using such an ancient Bugzilla version? Version 2.2 is *old*, like circa-1999-old.

Comment: Not my choice.  My company is planning to move to TFS *someday*, and is reluctant to change until then.  I'm trying to cobble together a temporary bug-workflow solution using VS Extensions and some interface in BZilla.